# Google Maps - point distance from polyline

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I have a some google maps polylines.
I'm trying to draw 2 polylines around them, so they make some kind of boundary:

[image]

So for each point of my original polyline I calculate the boundary line point, so it is lets say 25 meters from the original point:

```
function getOffsetPoints($p1, $p2, $p3, $distance = 25) {
    $gap = (180 / M_PI)  * ($distance / 6378137);
    $sx = $p3['lat'] - $p1['lat'];
    $sy = $p3['lng'] - $p1['lng'];
    $cx = $p2['lat']; $cy = $p2['lng'];

    $normx = $sy; $normy = -$sx;
    $length = sqrt($normx * $normx + $normy * $normy);
    $normx = $normx / $length; $normy = $normy / $length;
    
    $newx1 = $cx - $normx * $gap;
    $newy1 = $cy - $normy * $gap;
    $newx2 = $cx + $normx * $gap;
    $newy2 = $cy + $normy * $gap;

    return [
        ['lat'=>$newx1, 'lng'=>$newy1], 
        ['lat'=>$newx2, 'lng'=>$newy2]
    ];
}
```

For this example lets leave out the first and last point of the polyline. So I always look at the previous and next point, and calculate the offset of the center point.

I think it is working pretty good. When I plot out my original and newly calculated points, they are in a equal distance from the original point:

[image]
The black ones are the original points and the blue and red are the offset points.

Now I take all the data and draw it in a google map using polylines:

```
for (var i=0; i<offset_polylines.length; i++) {
    var oPath = offset_polylines[i];
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: offset_polylines,
        strokeColor: "#ffffff",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        map: map,
    });
}
```

In the result you can see, that the lines are clearly not in a same distance from the original yellow line. What's happening here? The more the line goes 'vertical' the less is the distance. Why is that? If I measure the distance on the map the difference between my 'horizontal line' on the picture and the 'vertical' one is 10 meters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that that ratio meters/degree is constant for latitude (N/S direction, along meridian), but changes for longitude direction depending on latitude with coefficient `Abs(Cos(Latitude))`, so 1 degree along parallel  at equator contains 111 km, but for 45 degree of nothern latitude - only 78 km.

Your calculation is rough approximation, so you can perhaps just multiply longitude differences (`$sx`) by coefficient `1/Abs(Cos($lat))` to diminish anisothropy.

More exact approach might include computation of coordinates by distance and azimuth as described [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). Don't forget about degrees and radians.

```
dlng = lng3 - lng1

bearing = atan2( sin(dlng)⋅cos(lat3), cos(lat1)⋅sin(lat3) − sin(lat1)⋅cos(lat3)⋅cos(dlng))

perpbearing1 =  bearing + Pi/2
perpbearing2 =  bearing - Pi/2

latperp = asin(sin(lat2)⋅cos(d/R) + cos(lat2)⋅sin(d/R)⋅ cos(perbearingX))
lonperp = lon2+atan2(sin(perpbearingX)⋅sin(d/R)⋅cos(lat2),cos(d/R)−sin(lat2)⋅sin(latperp))
```

Comment: The multiplication by 1/abs(cos($lat)) doesn't give me the right result, but tomorrow I'll give a try to the more exact approach.

Comment: My bad. I put the formula to the wrong place. Its working as it supposed to. But I'll take a look at your updated answer. Thank you!